# How to resolve the issues generated in deserializing the xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, deserialization

Following issue occured when deserializing xml file

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (3, 514). ---> System.NotSupportedException: XLinq
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadXmlNodes(Boolean elementCanBeType)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadTypedPrimitive(XmlQualifiedName type, Boolean elementCanBeType)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadTypedPrimitive(XmlQualifiedName type)
```

This is the Xml,i am trying to parse,

```
<ns0:Response xmlns:ns0="urn:ae:testwebsite:uniqueness:genericcontentsrs:1">
  <GenericContents>
    <ModuleId>1296</ModuleId>
    <Title>Getting around</Title>
    <Description>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, &lt;a target="_blank" href="http://google.com"&gt;google.com&lt;/a&gt;, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,&lt;br /&gt;
      &lt;br /&gt;Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, TEst&amp;rsquo;s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
    </Description>
    <BuildingId>0</BuildingId>
    <GeoCoordinateX></GeoCoordinateX>
    <GeoCoordinateY></GeoCoordinateY>
    <MainImage>http://testwebsite.com/testimage.jpg</MainImage>
    <PublicLink>http://testwebsite.com/testpage.aspx</PublicLink>
    <Subpages>
      <Page>
        <SSId>10</SSId>
        <Title>Tours &amp; tour operators</Title>
        <Image>http://testwebsite.com/testimage.jpg</Image>
        <ModuleUniqueName>tours.tour.operators</ModuleUniqueName>
      </Page>
      <Page>
        <SSId>7</SSId>
        <Title>Taxis</Title>
        <Image>http://testwebsite.com/testimage.jpg</Image>
        <ModuleUniqueName>taxis</ModuleUniqueName>
      </Page>
    </Subpages>
    <RelatedEntities>
      <Entity>
        <Id>36694</Id>
        <Type>Image</Type>
        <TypeDescription>Corniche Road</TypeDescription>
        <URL>http://testwebsite.com/testimage.jpg</URL>
        <Title>DataFolder/TestImage.jpg</Title>
      </Entity>
    </RelatedEntities>
  </GenericContents>
</ns0:Response>
```

And using following class to deserialize it,

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:ae:testwebsite:uniqueness:genericcontentsrs:1")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:ae:testwebsite:uniqueness:genericcontentsrs:1", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Response
{
    private GenericContents genericContentsField;       
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")]
    public GenericContents GenericContents
    {
        get{return this.genericContentsField;}
        set{this.genericContentsField = value;}
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class GenericContents
{
    private ushort moduleIdField;
    private string titleField;
    private string descriptionField;
    private byte buildingIdField;
    private object geoCoordinateXField;
    private object geoCoordinateYField;
    private string mainImageField;
    private string publicLinkField;
    private GenericContentsPage[] subpagesField;
    private GenericContentsRelatedEntities relatedEntitiesField;      
    public ushort ModuleId
    {
        get{return this.moduleIdField;}
        set{this.moduleIdField = value;}
    }       
    public string Title
    {
        get{return this.titleField;}
        set{this.titleField = value;}
    }       
    public string Description
    {
        get{return this.descriptionField;}
        set{this.descriptionField = value;}
    }
    public byte BuildingId
    {
        get{return this.buildingIdField;}
        set{this.buildingIdField = value;}
    }       
    public object GeoCoordinateX
    {
        get{return this.geoCoordinateXField;}
        set{this.geoCoordinateXField = value;}
    }        
    public object GeoCoordinateY
    {
        get{return this.geoCoordinateYField;}
        set{this.geoCoordinateYField = value;}
    }
    public string MainImage
    {
        get{return this.mainImageField;}
        set{this.mainImageField = value;}
    }        
    public string PublicLink
    {
        get{return this.publicLinkField;}
        set{this.publicLinkField = value;}
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Page", IsNullable = false)]
    public GenericContentsPage[] Subpages
    {
        get{return this.subpagesField;}
        set{this.subpagesField = value;}
    }

    public GenericContentsRelatedEntities RelatedEntities
    {
        get{return this.relatedEntitiesField;}
        set{this.relatedEntitiesField = value;}
    }
}


[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class GenericContentsPage
{
    private ushort sSIdField;
    private string titleField;
    private string imageField;
    private string moduleUniqueNameField;
    public ushort SSId
    {
        get{return this.sSIdField;}
        set{this.sSIdField = value;}
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get{return this.titleField;}
        set{this.titleField = value;}
    }

    public string Image
    {
        get{return this.imageField;}
        set{this.imageField = value;}
    }

    public string ModuleUniqueName
    {
        get{return this.moduleUniqueNameField;}
        set{this.moduleUniqueNameField = value;}
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class GenericContentsRelatedEntities
{
    private GenericContentsRelatedEntitiesEntity entityField;
    public GenericContentsRelatedEntitiesEntity Entity
    {
        get{return this.entityField;}
        set{this.entityField = value;}
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class GenericContentsRelatedEntitiesEntity
{
    private ushort idField;
    private string typeField;
    private string typeDescriptionField;
    private string uRLField;
    private string titleField;
    public ushort Id
    {
        get{return this.idField;}
        set{this.idField = value;}
    }
    public string Type
    {
        get{return this.typeField;}
        set{this.typeField = value;}
    }       
    public string TypeDescription
    {
        get{return this.typeDescriptionField;}
        set{this.typeDescriptionField = value;}
    }       
    public string URL
    {
        get{return this.uRLField;}
        set{this.uRLField = value;}
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get{return this.titleField;}
        set{this.titleField = value;}
    }
}
```

Help me resolving the issue

Comment: `&amp;` is not a valid xml entity (it's actually an html entity). How do you generate the xml file? You will have to correct the xml before deserializing it. If possible at the source.

Comment: @SteveB: not a predefined XML entity? There are 5 predefined entities: `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;` and `&quot;` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML  MSXML says that the XML is well-formed.

Comment: I think there is no problem with the entities.i think issue with WP8.Now i have tested,the same classes and desearilizing works with WP7 app in another machine.Is there any thing i am missing with WP8?

Comment: @ThomasW. You were right: http://dotnetfiddle.net/zBpR4z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the empty node values in the Xml file. I have modified the properties of deserializing class as Nullable.It is working fine.

Comment: I still did n't get why this issue is not raised when the application targeting to the Windows Phone 7.Also,I am referring the same namespaces for deserializing in both apps. Any way,it works with WP8 with Nullable datatypes for the properties

Answer (score -1):

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax says that ampersands MUST be escaped to & or similar. So that's okay.
- Obviously something's wrong. Maybe your XML. So remove major parts of it and find out which node causes the error.
- Maybe it's your class definition. So use XDocument.Load or .Parse to find out if the XML is correct and to know that your class definition has a bug. Simplify the class by removing parts from it and find out which field/property/attribute/causes the error.

Comment: "Maybe" answers and assumptions are not very helpful. As I have already written in my comment, the XML is wellformed according MSXML.